# How do I create a duplicate instance of object contained in a shared pointer in c++?

Tags: c++, shared-ptr, smart-pointers

I have an object which has both a copy constructor and assignment operator defined.  It is enclosed inside a shared pointer.

I want to make another shared pointer that contains a copy of the original shared pointer (i.e. new shared pointer to a new memory location, which however, has the same data as the original object).

Thanks for any assistance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You invoke the copy constructor when creating the new object:

```
std::shared_ptr<C> ptr1(new C());      // invokes the default constructor
std::shared_ptr<C> ptr2(new C(*ptr1)); // invokes the copy constructor
```

In this case, it's really no different than if you have regular, dumb pointers.

Comment: I find the question slightly hard to read, but is that what the OP is asking? Or are they asking how to create another shared pointer to the object?

Comment: @Martin:  I _think_ so, but I'm not sure now.  The "pointer to a new memory location" was what led me to this being the answer, but I could be wrong.

Comment: James you read my question correctly the first time, and the answer was exactly what I was looking for.

Reading back, I am amazed how you made any sense of my question.  Many hours of debugging had left my brain quite scrambled...

Thanks for the answe again.

Answer (score 1):

Often I'll be using shared pointers with polymoprphic types. In this case you can't use the method suggested by James McNellis.

```
class Base
{
 ...
  virtual void doSomething()=0;
};

class Derived : public Base
{
  ...
  void doSomething() { ... }
};

std::shared_ptr<Base> ptr(new Derived);
std::shared_ptr<Base> cpy( new Base( *ptr ) ); // THIS DOES NOT COMPILE!
```

So what I do instead is to add a clone function into the base class, and implement it in the derived classes.

```
class Base
{
 ...
  virtual void doSomething()=0;
  virtual std::shared_ptr<Base> clone() const =0;
};

class Derived : public Base
{
  ...
  void doSomething() { ... }
  std::shared_ptr<Base> clone() const 
  { 
     return std::shared_ptr<Base>( new Derived( *this ) );
  }
};


std::shared_ptr<Base> ptr(new Derived);
std::shared_ptr<Base> cpy = ptr->clone();
```

Comment: Actually the the top case does compile if you have no pure virtual functions. you just wont get a proper copy of the object, it'll get sliced to the base class...

Comment: And you probably want your clone method to return a Base*, so derived classes can take advantage of covarient return types

Comment: ... plus having `shared_ptr` in your class interface adds unneeded coupling. You are forcing (`shared_ptr` cannot relinquish ownership) your users into using an specific type of smart pointer regardless or their use of the data. They might prefer using `scoped_ptr`, or `unique_ptr`, or a pointer container that handles ownership. Maybe even their own (locking?) smart pointer... The decision of smart pointer should be in the receiving call, where the most information is known.

Comment: C++ gets very ham-fisted with this sort of thing. Writing a one-liner clone function for every descendant class? _Laaaaame._

Comment: @David Its a trade off, but returning a shared pointer allows me to control the destruction of the object, rather than the caller.  Otherwise using a caching, or my own allocators can lead to trouble. Now there are ways around some of those issues, but they'd obscure the core of the idea.

Comment: @Terry unfortunately you can't return smart pointers in a covariant manner. But if you want to use raw pointers in the return then using covariant return is certainly better.

Comment: If you really feel that you need to keep care of the memory for your users, return an `std::auto_ptr` or an `unique_ptr` where the user can actually release the object from that smart pointer and pass it into whatever choice of smart pointer they want to use. By returning `shared_ptr` you are forcing your decision on users.

Comment: @Michael I know, that was exactly my point. That's why I suggested changing the return type to Base*